# Compare Grand total of "Group by subtotals" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have data in the form of below table. I have applied an aggregate function of sum on the last column of Quantity(MG).

```
ITEM         STORE     Quantity(MG) 

Rice Bags     ABC      150 
Sugar Bags    ABC      200
Rice Bags     NEW      50 
Sugar Bags    New      20 
Rice Bags     Alpha    25
```

My Select SQL looks like this.

```
Select ITEM, STORE, SUM(Quantity(MG)
From....
.........
.........
Group by ITEM, STORE 
Having SUM(Quantity(MG) > 50
```

The Problem i am facing is with the having statement i want the SQL to compare the Grand sum of all the quantity values for a given item (lets say Rice Bags , which is 150 + 50 +25 = 225). But with the above query it's not working as expected. when i apply the condition "Having SUM(Quantity(MG) > 50" it actually compares the values 50 with each unique row and skip the rows where rice bags quantity is less than 50 (which in this case is row # 5).Ideally this row should not be skipped because the aggregate of Rice bags quantity is 225 so no row for rice bags should be skipped.

Whats the solution to apply such a filter with this group by setting?

Comment: Read up on window sets `over Partition by`...  They allow you to create inline aggregate totals. which can be then compared to other aggregates, without negatively impacting the base aggregation.  Cool stuff really.

Comment: `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((),())` may also be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a Group Sum on `Quantity(MG)`:

```
select ITEM, STORE, sumQuantity
from
 (
   Select ITEM, STORE, SUM(Quantity) as sumQuantity
      ,SUM(SUM(quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM) as groupSum 
   From....
   .........
   .........
   Group by ITEM, STORE
 ) as dt
where groupSum > 50
```

Answer (score 1):

sum() over(partition by) will do the job for you:

```
Select ITEM, STORE, SUM(Quantity(MG)) over(partition by item,store) as sm
From table
where Quantity(MG)< 50
```

**Edited:**

```
select ITEM, STORE,Quantity(MG),grp_sum from 
     (Select ITEM, STORE,Quantity(MG), SUM(Quantity(MG)) over(partition by item,store) as grp_sum
        From table)temp
        where grp_sum< 50
```

Comment: This changes all the values in Quantity column to grand totals. I don't want any change to the subtotals showing up in rows currently. I just want another command which filters outs the records having an aggregate sum less then 50.

Comment: Window function in where clause?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
;with cte as(select item, store, quantity, sum(quantity) over(partition by item) as groupedQuantity)
select item, store, sum(quantity) as quantity
from cte
where groupedQuantity > 50
group by item, store
```